# Is it even possible call SHOW/DROP/ALTER/CALL statements within the body of Netezza Stored Procedure?

Tags: stored-procedures, netezza

I am new to Netezza stored procedures. I am going through the IBM's documentation. I want to ask whether is it possible to call SHOW/DROP/ALTER PROCEDURE command within the body of another procedure like so:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_proc() RETURNS boolean LANGUAGE NZPLSQL AS BEGIN_PROC
BEGIN
--any SHOW/DROP/ALTER/CALL PROCEDURE commands
RETURN TRUE;
END;
END_PROC;
```

Can these commands be used in a procedure body or do they come standalone ?

Answer (score 0):

You Can definitely CALL or EXECUTE other stored procedures. Haven’t tried to ALTEE/CREATE them though, but try it out :)